# Find value of light intensity at any given point in three.js

Tags: three.js

I have added light to my scene as follows:

```
var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xFFF1E0 ,1,200,Math.PI/4);
spotLight.position.set( -wallWidth/2,wallHeight/2,100);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
spotLight.shadowCameraNear = camera.near;
spotLight.shadowCameraFar = camera.far;
spotLight.shadowDarkness = 0.4;
spotLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;
spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 4096;
spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 4096;
spotLight.name = 'Light';
scene.add( spotLight );
```

My scene contains, say, a cube. Now, I want to find out the value of the intensity of light at any point in my scene. Is there a way I can find the intensity of light at any point, say, if i click?

Comment: yes, overall you should take a look at barycentric coordinates, ray/plane intersection and light flux. You shoot a ray from where you click, intersect your objects, figure out the normal at that intersection, test it against the lights (distance/angle) and you should get your intensity in lumens.

Comment: The intensity of light at any pixel in your screen is the value of that pixel; minus the color.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
@gaitat: I think the color of a pixel can be easily found out by intersects[0].object.material.color.getHex();
However, I am unable to figure out a way to get the pixel's value.

Comment: @pailhead
Thanks for your reply. Your method worked well. However, now my scene has multiple light sources. Thus I feel the method suggested by gaitat is right on target. If only i could figure out how to get a pixel's value.

Answer (score 1):

The intensity of light at any pixel in your screen is the value of that pixel; minus the color.

So what you need to do is pass `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` to your renderer in order to be able to get its image data.

```
renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
```

Then in your `render()` function you get the data of your `renderer.domElement` and you are set. (Some math required to go to a specific pixel)

```
function render()
{
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    imgData = renderer.domElement.toDataURL();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just measuring the pixel value will give you a pretty arbitrary number, it's not exactly 'light intensity' or am i overthinking this?

In any case, if you want to read the pixel value from the frame buffer:

```
var myRenderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
var myGLcontext = myRenderer.getContext();
var myResult = myGLcontext.readPixels( x , y , width , height , myGLcontext.RGBA , myGLcontext.UNSIGNED_BYTE );
```